# How to get data from Firestore in Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to know what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm calling this function from Flutter. The call back is getting done correctly and the first & second prints are coming in the "log" on Firbase. But getting undefined from the "Firestore"!!

This is the code in the Cloud Function:

```
var functions = require("firebase-functions");
let admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
admin.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });


exports.storeContact5 = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // First print is working fine
    console.log('test');
    var recieverId = 'WqHxLoYvRxR9UK8sFJZ9WxTOIE32';
    const check = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(recieverId).get();
    check.then(testValue => {
        console.log(testValue.data.nickname);
        return true;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting document', err);
    });
    console.log('test2');
    // Return to flutter App (Working fine)
    return {
        repeat_message: 'ok!'
    }
});
```

Screenshot for Firebase Log

[image]

Comment: @RahulMahadik - This is Cloud Function code!

Answer (score 5):

You should do `testValue.data().nickname` and not `testValue.data.nickname`, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data.

Also, you should return a result only once and you should not return outside of the `.then()` if you want to return the result of the asynchronous operation.

In addition, see here how to handle errors: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors

So you may do as follows:

```
exports.storeContact5 = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // First print is working fine
    console.log('test');
    var recieverId = 'WqHxLoYvRxR9UK8sFJZ9WxTOIE32';
    const check = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(recieverId).get();
    return check.then(testValue => {
        console.log(testValue.data().nickname);
        return {repeat_message: 'ok!'};
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting document', err);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('Error getting document', err);
    });
});
```

I would suggest you watch the videos from the official series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/, in particular the ones titled "Learn JavaScript Promises"